# Sending csv file date to json body dynamically

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm trying to send a JSON request in JMeter

```json
{
    "rejectedData": [{
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "p": "2",
            "v": "1235.00",
            "ap": "1",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-PP2324420220620",
            "c": "SERVICE",
            "et": 1737527418861343711,
            "rm": "OTR"
        },
        {
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "p": "500",
            "v": "500.00",
            "ap": "1",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-PP2324420220620",
            "c": "CHANNEL",
            "et": "1737527418861343711",
            "rm": "NO VALID ACTIVITY CODE"
        },
        {
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "p": "250",
            "v": "250.00",
            "ap": "1",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-PP2324520220620",
            "c": "CHANNEL",
            "et": 1737527418861343711,
            "rm": "PARTIAL PAYMENT"
        }
    ],
    "pointAdjustedBillsInfo": [{
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "m": "08/2022",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "ap": "3",
            "av": "10.00",
            "bn": "GST97452",
            "bd": "2022-08-10",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-P2277120220620",
            "c": "SERVICE",
            "et": 1737527418861343711
        },
        {
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "m": "08/2022",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "ap": "55",
            "av": "55.00",
            "bn": "GST97455",
            "bd": "2022-08-12",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-P2272520220622",
            "c": "CHANNEL",
            "et": 173756017284618951
        }
    ],
    "pointsReversalInfo": [{
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "rp": "10",
            "rv": "10.00",
            "rb": "GST97452",
            "rd": "2022-08-10",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-P2277120220620",
            "c": "SERVICE",
            "et": 173756017284618951
        },
        {
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "413450",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "rp": "30",
            "rv": "30.00",
            "rb": "GST97455",
            "rd": "2022-08-10",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-P227520220620",
            "c": "CHANNEL",
            "et": 1737527418861343711
        }
    ],
    "pointsEarnedInfo": [{
            "bi": "20200624061722601",
            "r": "4134501s",
            "m": "08/2022",
            "ac": "34355466",
            "h": "HUL-1000067687",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-P2277120220620",
            "io": "90SMN00047D-P2277120220620",
            "bn": "GST97452",
            "sr": "NA",
            "p": "50"
        },
        {
            "bi": "HUL-1000067687",
            "r": "413450",
            "m": "08/2022",
            "ac": "34355466",
            "h": "HHUL-1000067687",
            "o": "90SMNSKAPPD-P2277120220620",
            "io": "90SMN00047D-P2277120220620",
            "bn": "GST97452",
            "sr": "STR15341",
            "p": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of hardcoding the values I am saving them in a CSV file, need to send the entire dynamically

Comment: please include the code that you already have, and add more specifics

Comment: currently I am figuring out how to script this , and I am newbie to this . the entire json data should be read dynamically

Comment: def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    @groovy.transform.Immutable
class rejectedData {
    String bi
    String r
    String h
}
def villas = new File("GeneralApi.csv")
    .readLines()
        .collect { line ->
            new rejectedData(line.split(",")[0], line.split(",")[1], line.split(",")[2])}
 builder(
    Child :rejectedData.collect(),
        }

    )
     log.info(builder.toPrettyString())
     vars.put("payload", builder.toPrettyString())

Comment: Could please anyone help me here, I need to write a script - loop for the entire data  to fetch from csv file . all the data within "" should be taken dynamically, and also example  - pointsReversalInfo .I am trying to create 4 separate csv files for the same . but i am unable to go forward

Comment: sorry, I meant, please update you original post with these details; comments are not meant for this purpose